# Can't change JTable Header background color

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to change the background of the header in jTable in a GUI application.
 I have tried this as of now

The setForeground works but the setBackground doesn't work.

Any other alternatives to change the Background?

Code I've tried:-

```
  jTable1.getTableHeader().setOpaque(false);
  jTable1.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Calisto MT", Font.BOLD, 40));
  jTable1.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(247,99,143));
  jTable1.getTableHeader().setForeground(new Color(12,99,11));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jTable1.getTableHeader().setOpaque(false);
```

Setting a component non-opaque means the component is transparent so the background is never painted. Get rid of that statement.

All you need is:

```
jTable1.getTableHeader().setBackground(new Color(247,99,143));
```

If it doesn't work then the problem could be the LAF you are using.

Comment: it doesn't work even after following ^ Can you please brief about *the LAF* you're talking about. Thank you.

Comment: For example, I think Nimbus does some custom painting of components. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. That is create a JFrame with just a JTable and the above code. Then update your question with the code and the platform you are using. Then others can test the code as see if they have the same problem.